# Partition List on sublists where first and last elements of neighbour sublists are the same

Tags: java, list, split, element, overlap

There is List of Objects:

```
[Object1, Object2, Object3, Object4, Object5]
```

It should be splitted to following structure:

```
[
    [Object1, Object2, Object3]
    [Object3, Object4, Object5]
]
```

this code gives split without overlap of last element of sublist:

```
Streams.stream(Iterables.partition(maps,3)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the result is:

```
   [Object1, Object2, Object3]
   [Object4, Object5]
```

**Object3** is missed here.

Is there elegant way to split this `List` with repeating 
 last element of previous sublist as the first element of next sublist?

I have tried this way, but it looks not so elegant as I wish:

```
List<List<String>> res= new ArrayList<>();
for (int y = 0; y < input.size() - 1;) {
    List<String> sub = paths.subList(y, y += 3);
    res.add(sub)
    --y;
}
```

Comment: Adding the appropriate language tag would probably be just as helpful in getting your question answered as posting a bounty on it.

Comment: How should the lists be partitioned if there are seven items? `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7]]`?

Comment: @beaker  thanks ,done

Comment: @sergionni can you please review the answer below

Comment: @ Krishna Sharma I have posted my way recently and it looks shorter, however I want it to be more elegant, something like smart partitioning with backstep
`Iterables.partition()`

Answer (score 4):

A [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) solution with streams, where [`Intstream.iterate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) has the following signature with only 2 args:

```
IntStream iterate(int seed, IntUnaryOperator f)
```

as follows:

```
List res = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + step - 1)
        .limit(input.size() / (step - 1))
        .mapToObj(i -> input.subList(i, Math.min(i + step, input.size())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With a `step` size of 3, Output:

```
[[a, b, c]]             //List<String> input = Arrays.asList("a","b","c");
[[a, b, c], [c, d]]     //List<String> input = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d");
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using `iterate` with two args and then `limit` instead of `iterate` with three args?

Comment: There is no benefit. It's a java 8 solution where iterate with 3 arg is not available (unlike Java 9)

Comment: Ah, did not even know this. In this case, good addition. Added a note to my answer, too.

Comment: @tobias_k sure 

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would just go with a variant of the loop that you currently have, but move the increment to the loop head. Also note that your code only works if the list is perfectly divisible, hence the `Math.min` in my version.

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> split(List<T> input, int k) {
    List<List<T>> res= new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size() - 1; i += k-1) {
        res.add(input.subList(i, Math.min(input.size(), i + k)));
    }
    return res;
}
```

Or if you prefer Streams, you can use [`IntStream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntPredicate-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-)<sup>1</sup>:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> split(List<T> input, int k) {
    return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < input.size(), i -> i + k-1)
            .mapToObj(i -> input.subList(i, Math.min(input.size(), i + k)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Example, for both versions:

```
List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
System.out.println(split(input, 3));
// [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9], [9, 10]]
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> Note: The three-parameter-version is available in Java 9+; see [Pankaj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51909596/1639625) for Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, out of them here is the elegant approach.

```
public class SplitList {

    public static <T> List<List<T>> split(List<T> list) {
        if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("List shouldn't be empty");
        }

        int[] positions = {0, (list.size() + 1) / 2, list.size()};

        boolean isListOdd = list.size() % 2 != 0;

        return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 1)
                .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(positions[i] + (isListOdd ? (i != 0 ? -1 : 0) : 0), positions[i + 1]))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
        System.out.println(split(list));
    }
}
```

Here is the output

```
[[A, B, C], [C, D, E]]
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants. The result is the same in this case, but You just divide the list in half, repeating the middle element if the size is odd. OP seems to want to have sublists of size k (3 in this case) with the first element of each sublist being the last element of the one before that.

Comment: May be, but the problem is requirement is incomplete. I have posted this answer considering he wants to split the list with equal number of elements, to do that if list size is odd add the last element of first list into the second list as a first element. otherwise if list size are equals just partition the list in two equal list.